# Chart.js Bar Chart coloring Technique

Tags: chart.js

Hi Everyone i just want to ask question about bar chart in this application http://www.chartjs.org/

is it possible to create a bar with 2 colors?

for example i have a target 1000 and reach 500

so the full length of bar is color blue(target) then the 50% length of the bar is color red(reach)?

sorry for my question if it is confusing thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that a posible solution could be use some kind of Stacked Bar.
But chart.js doesn't support that out of the box, It looks like that you need the a fork of chart.js called chartnew.js that allow stacked bar which could give you this two colors in the same bar and many other options. Take a look at the github page of the project

https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/

I hope it helps